# Chrome adressbar issue while content is changing

Tags: html, css, scroll

I've noticed a problem with the chrome browser adressbar since chrome version 73 on mobile devices.
I have a page with a huge amount of content, so it is necessary to scroll down to see all the content. While scrolling, the browser adressbar hides. At the bottom of the page is an button to go further. After clicking the bottom, the content changes and a "white stripe/ content" appears. Those "white stripe/content" has the same height as the adressbar of the browser. It stays until I scroll to the top.

The basic html file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="FRI, 13 APR 1999 01:00:00 GMT">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width,
            initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="../content/myApp.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script>
        function loadContent() {
            document.getElementById('intro').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <div class="toolbar flex-display flex-alignCenter flex-row
                    flex-spaceB kd_color1">
                    <div class="flex-display flex-alignCenter">
                        <div class="css_toolbar_menu_btn material-flex
                            text-left">
                            <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-clear"
                                data-toogle="offcanvas" id="btn_menu"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="css_breadcrumb flex-display flex-row">
                            <div class="hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon
                                    glyphicon-apple">toolbar</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-display flex-alignCenter flex-row flex-end
                        flex-ItemCenterJ toolbox">
                        <div class="css_toolbarIcon">
                            <div>
                                <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-clear
                                    css_toolbarBtn hidden-xs"">
                                    <span class="sr-only"></span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-clear
                                    css_toolbarBtn hidden-xs">
                                    <span class="sr-only"></span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="main-ctrl-start" class="">
                <div>
                    <div class="lead text-left css_textContainer" id="intro">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Fugit, laboriosam tenetur ullam, nam distinctio in ipsa
                        repellendus consequatur unde reiciendis maiores eaque
                        quos soluta voluptas! Consequatur ex sapiente culpa
                        est!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                        elit. Fugit, laboriosam tenetur ullam, nam distinctio in
                        ipsa repellendus consequatur unde reiciendis maiores
                        eaque quos soluta voluptas! Consequatur ex sapiente
                        culpa est!
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Fugit, laboriosam tenetur ullam, nam distinctio in ipsa
                        repellendus consequatur unde reiciendis maiores eaque
                        quos soluta voluptas! Consequatur ex sapiente culpa est!
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Fugit, laboriosam tenetur ullam, nam distinctio in ipsa
                        repellendus consequatur unde reiciendis maiores eaque
                        quos soluta voluptas! Consequatur ex sapiente culpa est!
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Fugit, laboriosam tenetur ullam, nam distinctio in ipsa
                        repellendus consequatur unde reiciendis maiores eaque
                        quos soluta voluptas! Consequatur ex sapiente culpa est!
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Fugit, laboriosam tenetur ullam, nam distinctio in ipsa
                        repellendus consequatur unde reiciendis maiores eaque
                        quos soluta voluptas! Consequatur ex sapiente culpa est!
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Fugit, laboriosam tenetur ullam, nam distinctio in ipsa
                        repellendus consequatur unde reiciendis maiores eaque
                        quos soluta voluptas! Consequatur ex sapiente culpa est!
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Fugit, laboriosam tenetur ullam, nam distinctio in ipsa
                        repellendus consequatur unde reiciendis maiores eaque
                        quos soluta voluptas! Consequatur ex sapiente culpa est!
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Fugit, laboriosam tenetur ullam, nam distinctio in ipsa
                        repellendus consequatur unde reiciendis maiores eaque
                        quos soluta voluptas! Consequatur ex sapiente culpa est!
                    </div>
                    <div id="content" style="display: none;">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Velit, dignissimos! Sit vero, tempore porro magnam
                        laudantium inventore eos et, quia enim sint, repellendus
                        quae doloremque itaque tenetur atque eaque sequi.
                        <br>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Veritatis voluptatem, numquam cumque nisi omnis, quod
                        accusamus error quasi consequatur iusto necessitatibus,
                        similique itaque libero quis vel voluptas eius placeat
                        sunt.
                    </div>
                    <div class="css_btnGroup">
                        <div class="flex-display flex-row flex-spaceA">
                            <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-primary
                                flex-display"
                                onclick="loadContent()">
                                <div>
                                    next
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

thy related style.css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto_Regular;
  src: url(fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto_Light;
  src: url("fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf") format("truetype");
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
*,
:after,
:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  direction: ltr;
  overscroll-behavior-y: none;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

body {
  line-height: 150%;
  font-family: Roboto_Light, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

body.splashscreen {
  background: #fff;
}

.css_wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn-myAppDefault {
  z-index: 1;
  /*wird in kundenskin überschrieben, wenn button angepasst werden sollen*/
  background: #e6e4e1;
  border: #e6e4e1;
  color: #333;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  -o-transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 0.4em 0.2em 1em;
}

.btn-myAppDefault:active,
.btn-myAppDefault:focus,
.btn-myAppDefault:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  background: #e6e4e1;
  border: #e6e4e1;
  color: #333;
}

.btn-myAppDefault > div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 0.4em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 5em;
}

.btn-myAppDefault > div span.glyphicon:first-child {
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  margin: 0;
}

.btn-myAppDefault > div span.glyphicon:last-child {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  margin: 0;
}
.btn-myAppDisabled {
  opacity: 0.2;
  cursor: default;
}

.btn:active {
  /* disable box-shadow @ myApp-navbar icons */
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.css_btnGroup_space > div {
  margin: 0 1em;
}

#intro {
  margin: 1em 0 4.8em;
}

#intro .btn-myAppDefault {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.btn {
  border: 0 solid transparent;
}

.btn-clear {
  background: none;
}

.toolbar > div:not(.toolbox) {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.toolbar {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #ccc;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #ccc;
  height: 2.2em;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 -15px 0.4em;
}

.toolbar div {
  display: inline;
}

.toolbar .css_breadcrumb div {
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.toolbar .visible-xs {
  display: inline !important;
}
.css_toolbarIcon:last-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.flex-display {
  display: -webkit-box !important;
  display: -ms-flexbox !important;
  display: -moz-flex !important;
  display: -webkit-flex !important;
  display: flex !important;
}

.flex-row {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 0;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-flex: 1 1 0;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 0;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-column {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-start {
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -moz-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-end {
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -moz-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex-alignCenter {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-spaceB {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-spaceA {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-align-content: space-around;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.flex-spaceC {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.flex-stretch {
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -moz-box-align: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-toColumn {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-toRow {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-alignEnd {
  -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-item-align: end;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.flex-ItemCenterJ {
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.flex-flow {
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-roundSuccess {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
  -ms-align-content: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn:active,
.btn:focus,
.btn:hover,
body a:active,
body a:focus,
body a:hover {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.kd_fontColor {
  color: #333333;
}

.kd_color1 {
  background: #cecac5;
}

.kd_color1 *,
.kd_color1 *:hover,
.kd_color1 *:active,
.kd_color1 *:focus {
  color: #333333;
}

.kd_color1-rgb {
  background: rgba(206, 202, 197, 0.7);
}

.kd_color1-rgb *,
.kd_color1-rgb *:hover,
.kd_color1-rgb *:active,
.kd_color1-rgb *:focus {
  color: #333333;
}

.kd_color2 {
  background: #1d3061;
}

.css-code-container {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

/*=============================================================================*/
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  .flex-toColumn {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .flex-toRow {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .flex-alignEndPortrait {
    -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-item-align: end;
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
}

@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  body.intro .container {
    padding-bottom: 36px;
    margin-bottom: -36px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* tablet */
}

@media (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  /* tablet portrait */
}
@media (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  /* tablet landscape */
  body {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .toolbar div {
    padding: 0.1em 0 0.1em 0;
  }

  .css_wrapper {
    margin: 0 2em;
  }

  .toolbar {
    padding: 0 30px;
    margin-bottom: 1.6em;
  }

  #load_page .flexWrapper {
    margin-top: 2em;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.6em;
  }

  .toolbar {
    font-size: 1em;
  }

  body.intro .container {
    padding-bottom: 48px;
    margin-bottom: -48px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 728px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  body.intro {
    min-height: 728px;
    height: 100%;
  }

  html {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) and (min-height: 828px) {
  body {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
}
```

Step 1:
- content shows up

[image: content to scroll]

Step 2:

- scroll down and make sure that the browser adress bar hides [image: scrolling]

Step 3:

- click on button to change content
- view is completly visible (toolbar)
- adressbar from browser is still hidden
- "white stripe" appear at the bottom

[image: whitebar]

**Question**

Is it possible to make the adressbar visible again without any chrome::flags?
I tried to force scrolling with `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` but it won't help.
Maybe it's an CSS problem of my body and container tag?

Comment: @Pete: Don't get you. I described the problem. I showed up the behaviour and the reproducibility. I added code to reproduce the problem and last but not least I asked a specific question for that topic.

Comment: well then I'm going to refactor it

Comment: Edited question.